# Spark Overlap algorithm using Dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a data-source with fields: `product_id` - `product` - `start_time` - `end_time`

I am trying to build the logic for catching **Overlapping Records** for the same `product` (based on `start_time` and `end_time`) using the Dataframe functions.

```
------------------------------------------------
| product_id | product | start_time | end_time |
------------------------------------------------
|      1     | bottle  |     2      |    4     |
|      2     | bottle  |     3      |    5     |
|      3     | bottle  |     2      |    3     |
|      4     | bottle  |     6      |    7     |
|      1     |   can   |     2      |    4     |
|      2     |   can   |     5      |    6     |
|      3     |   can   |     2      |    4     |
```

I'd like to receive in output

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| product_id_a | product_id_b | product | start_time_a | end_time_a | start_time_b | end_time_b |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1      |       2      | bottle  |      2       |     4      |      3       |     5      |
|       1      |       3      | bottle  |      2       |     4      |      2       |     3      |
```

Because `bottle_1` has overlapping times with `bottle_2` and `bottle_3`, where 2 records are overlapping if the following conditions are satisfied:

- `max(a.start_time, b.start_time) < min(a.end_time, b.end_time)`
- `!(a.start_time == b.start_time && a.end_time == b.end_time)`
- `a.start_time != b.start_time || a.end_time != b.end_time`

where the last 2 conditions just specify that I am not interested in cases in which `start_time` and `end_time` are equal (e.g. `can_1` and `can_3` are not in the expected result even if they have same `start_time` and `end_time`).

For how the problem is structured is easy to think to a solution with MapReduce using RDD, but I am interested to a **solution with Dataframes**.

**HINT**: is there any chance that with `groupBy().agg()` is possible to specify an interesting condition that reaches the described logic?

For any further explanation feel free to ask

**NOT DUPLICATE** of [How to aggregate over rolling time window with groups in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711716/how-to-aggregate-over-rolling-time-window-with-groups-in-spark)

Unfortunately in the reported answer has been used `F.lag`, which in my case is not a good enough condition: F.lag uses a comparison with the previous record only, but in the reported example would not work as desired since that `bottle_1` would not be reported as overlapping with `bottle_3` because they are not consecutive records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```scala
df.join(cloneDf, $"label").where($"label" !== $"label1").where($"min" < $"max1").where($"min1" < $"max").show()
```

You need to make Cartesian product of `DataFrame` to check, if rows overlap, you can map them then however you want. Of course, you need to omit self - two same `Row`s overlap.

The whole code:

```scala
val df = SparkEmbedded.ss.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, 2, 5),
  (2, 4, 7),
  (3, 6, 9)
)).toDF("product_id", "min", "max")
import SparkEmbedded.ss.implicits._
val cloneDf = df.select(df.columns.map(col):_*)
    .withColumnRenamed("product_id", "product_id1")
    .withColumnRenamed("min", "min1")
    .withColumnRenamed("max", "max1")
df.crossJoin(cloneDf)
  .where($"product_id" < $"product_id1")
  .where($"min" < $"max1")
  .where($"min1" < $"max").show()
```

I have split `where` clause for clarity.

The result is:

```
+-----+---+---+------+----+----+
|label|min|max|label1|min1|max1|
+-----+---+---+------+----+----+
|    1|  2|  5|     2|   4|   7|
|    2|  4|  7|     3|   6|   9|
+-----+---+---+------+----+----+
```

The example is in Scala, but Python has similar API.

Comment: thanks a lot! Both solutions (yours and @user11013893) helped me to solve my problem! Your solution has `where($"label" < $"label1")` which helped me to avoid duplicated results, while the other provided more interesting functions. Probably the `crossJoin` was not necessary: a normal inner join based on `product` (see the example) was enough. I don't understand why my question was down-voted (same for your answer which I up-voted). But I think that your answer was more useful with the use of the `< condition` in  `where($"label" < $"label1")`. I'll accept yours

Comment: to help readability of the answer, could you edit your post and make it closer to the example that I reported? So change `where($"label" < $"label1")` to `where($"product_id" < $"product_id1")`, the join based on `product`... and so on

Comment: I suggest putting the python code in separate answer as it changes the programming style completely.

Comment: I started working with ML with python, but it was too dynamic for me. Scala is perfect (professionally I develop in Java) ;>

Answer (score 2):

Each of the conditions can be translated directly into SQL

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, least, greatest

cond1 = (
    greatest(col("a.start_time"), col("b.start_time")) < 
    least(col("a.end_time"), col("b.end_time"))
)

cond2 = ~(
    (col("a.start_time") == col("b.start_time")) & 
    (col("a.end_time") == col("b.end_time"))
)

cond3 = (
    (col("a.start_time") != col("b.start_time")) | 
    (col("a.end_time") != col("b.end_time"))
)
```

so you can just join and filter.

```
(df.alias("a").join(df.alias("b"), ["product"]).filter(cond1 & cond2 & cond3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Andronicus [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54521846/4725074) I came up with this approach in pure Python.

It was necessary to join the `DataFrame` with himself to check if rows overlap. Of course, you need to omit self with the condition `df.product_id < duplicate_df.product_id` (two same `Row` and the reversed `product_id`s overlap).

The whole code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "bottle", 2, 4),
     (2, "bottle", 3, 5),
     (3, "bottle", 2, 3),
     (4, "bottle", 6, 7),
     (1, "can", 2, 4),
     (2, "can", 5, 6),
     (3, "can", 2, 4)], 
     ['product_id', 'product', 'start_time', 'end_time'])

duplicate_df = df

conditions = [df.product == duplicate_df.product,
              df.product_id < duplicate_df.product_id,
              df.start_time != duplicate_df.start_time, 
              df.end_time != duplicate_df.end_time,
              F.least(df.end_time, duplicate_df.end_time) >
              F.greatest(df.start_time, duplicate_df.start_time)]

df.join(duplicate_df, conditions)
```