# Pyspark Window Function to count Txns in Last Hour by Row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df like the one in the example below - it is sorted in descending timeframe. I want to calculate by row the numbers of txns in the last hour - it would be at least 1 (the current), but could be of course more

I am using an approach I modified from [How to aggregate over rolling time window with groups in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711716/how-to-aggregate-over-rolling-time-window-with-groups-in-spark)

But it is not working and I am at a loss

I expect the first row will yield 1, the second 4, the third 3, the fourth 2 and the fifth 1

I would also like to get the maximum index of those txns that are counted ( ihave not worked on that if I get the first part I think I can modify it to do that too)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

schema = StructType([
   StructField("datetime_string", StringType(), True),
   StructField("group_by", StringType(), True),
    StructField("index", IntegerType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(datetime_string='2022-01-05 04:12:18', group_by='group1', index=1),
                            Row(datetime_string='2022-01-05 02:43:19', group_by='group1', index=2),
                            Row(datetime_string='2022-01-05 02:23:30', group_by='group1', index=3),
                            Row(datetime_string='2022-01-05 02:20:38', group_by='group1', index=4),
                            Row(datetime_string='2022-01-05 02:18:39', group_by='group1', index=5)
                            ],schema)

#create the timestamp and a version in seconds for math later on
df = (df
      .withColumn('timestamp',F.to_timestamp(F.col('datetime_string')))
      .withColumn('ts_seconds',F.col('timestamp').cast('long'))
     )


w = (Window()
   .partitionBy(F.col("group_by"))
   .orderBy(F.desc('ts_seconds'))
   .rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    )

diff = F.max('ts_seconds').over(w) - F.col('ts_seconds')
indicator = (diff < 60*60 ).cast("Integer")
subgroup = F.sum(indicator).over(w)

df1 = (df
       .withColumn('txns_last_hour',subgroup)
      )

df1.show()
```

what I get is this

```
|    datetime_string|group_by|index|          timestamp|ts_seconds|txns_last_hour|
+-------------------+--------+-----+-------------------+----------+--------------+
|2022-01-05 04:12:18|  group1|    1|2022-01-05 04:12:18|1641377538|             5|
|2022-01-05 02:43:19|  group1|    2|2022-01-05 02:43:19|1641372199|             4|
|2022-01-05 02:23:30|  group1|    3|2022-01-05 02:23:30|1641371010|             3|
|2022-01-05 02:20:38|  group1|    4|2022-01-05 02:20:38|1641370838|             2|
|2022-01-05 02:18:39|  group1|    5|2022-01-05 02:18:39|1641370719|             1|
```

If someone can be graceful enough to explain what am I doing wrong I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Use `rangeBetween` instead of `rowsBetween` for the Window frame boundaries. Also, your Window ordering isn't correct. From the result you expect it seems you need to order on ascending not descending.

Try with following modifications:

```
w = (Window()
     .partitionBy(F.col("group_by"))
     .orderBy('ts_seconds')
     .rangeBetween(-60*60, Window.currentRow)
     )

df1 = (df
       .withColumn('txns_last_hour', F.count("*").over(w))
       .orderBy(F.desc("ts_seconds"))
       )

df1.show()

#+-------------------+--------+-----+-------------------+----------+--------------+
#|    datetime_string|group_by|index|          timestamp|ts_seconds|txns_last_hour|
#+-------------------+--------+-----+-------------------+----------+--------------+
#|2022-01-05 04:12:18|  group1|    1|2022-01-05 04:12:18|1641352338|             1|
#|2022-01-05 02:43:19|  group1|    2|2022-01-05 02:43:19|1641346999|             4|
#|2022-01-05 02:23:30|  group1|    3|2022-01-05 02:23:30|1641345810|             3|
#|2022-01-05 02:20:38|  group1|    4|2022-01-05 02:20:38|1641345638|             2|
#|2022-01-05 02:18:39|  group1|    5|2022-01-05 02:18:39|1641345519|             1|
#+-------------------+--------+-----+-------------------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - I see the range Between is relative -